# Where to check which JXBrowser & Selenium matched version?

Tags: java, selenium, version, jxbrowser

I read along the Release Notes of each JXBrowser's Versions at the moment. But still not found any official page stating the matched (working) version that works to the Selenium library except **only ONE**.

CMIIW, but [the page (link)](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013135-jxbrowser-selenium) only said:

**This approach was tested with Selenium WebDriver 2.46 and ChromeDriver 2.16.**

And what about the JXBrowser version itself... which **JXBrowser version** is matched to **Selenium**, etc....

What about **JXBrowser 6.22** is it fine with **Selenium 2.46** or something? Where is the page matching (working) release notes for this case actually? (sorry i'm a bit confused).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All JxBrowser versions are compatible with Selenium WebDriver. The approach described in this [article](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013135-jxbrowser-selenium) is the only way JxBrowser works with Selenium.

As for the "**This approach was tested with Selenium WebDriver 2.46 and ChromeDriver 2.16.**"
These are actual versions of Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver used for testing with JxBrowser. JxBrowser was not tested with the older/newer versions of Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver, so the smooth work with other versions is not guaranteed, though it may work without any issues.

Comment: yes. that's the case! I wish they have the smooth work for the older/newer version with the good documentation written. Thanks @Serhii

Comment: Well ! my curiosity for finding support of Selenium for JxBrowser brought me here. And to let you all know, latest selenium version with latest chromedriver is not able to attach to the remote debugging port of my AUT using JxBrowser.