# Cant initialize remote JxBrowser using Chromedriver and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, javafx, automation, jxbrowser

I am trying to automate a JavaFx application which has an integrated web page for loggin in.
I am using the code found here: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013135-jxbrowser-selenium
and every thing is working great on my local machine.
The issue is that I need to open the application on a remote machine and integrate with it as well.
The above code will not work, I am getting

```
unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 192.168.2.147:9222
from chrome not reachable
```

ERROR.

I have tried another method not using the chromeDriverService but using selenium grid and it looks like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

String remoteDebuggingAddress = add + ":9222";

options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", remoteDebuggingAddress);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);

jxDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + add + ":5555" + "/wd/hub"), capabilities);
return jxDriver;
```

I run the hub on port 5555 and the node on the machine machine.
The chromeDriver is in the path envVar, and I see in the cmd window that a connection request is sent.
The result is the same.

Can anyone please advise what am I doing wrong here?
Can this remote jxbroswer automation possible?

EDIT:
When I initialize a Chrome session on the remote machine it works as expected (using selenium grid) but when I add

```
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", remoteDebuggingAddress);
```

it fails with same error.

Comment: Did you setup chrome driver location of remote machine ?

Comment: as i mentioned, the chrome driver is in PATH on the remote mahcine and in the grid node outout i can see he is starting chromeDriver, but fails to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find the solution for this and the problem was the IP that I sent to "debuggerAddress".
While I sent the remote machine IP I should have used "localhost" as the connection was already established using the selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 192.168.2.147:9222 from chrome not reachable
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

As far as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controlled [jxbrowser](/questions/tagged/jxbrowser) is concerned you are following the correct [documentation](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013135-jxbrowser-selenium).

However, in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744365/where-to-check-which-jxbrowser-selenium-matched-version) @SerhiiFedchenko mentioned, this particular approach was tested with **Selenium WebDriver 2.46** and **ChromeDriver 2.16**. *JxBrowser* was not tested with the older/newer versions of Selenium WebDriver and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327).

---

### Solution

A possible solution would be to execute your test with the tested version of the binaries:

- *Selenium WebDriver 2.46*
- *ChromeDriver 2.16*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but our application is using chromium 69.x.x and ChromeDriver 2.16 is not supported.

Another thing that I checked is starting a regular chrome seesion, while I am able to start a chrome browser seesion on the remote machine, if I add the "debuggerAddress" to chromeOptions, it fails, so I guess the problem is somewhere with this flag.